# Choose one no empty of two fields for __str__()

Tags: python, django

In my model I have two fields for the title, one for language. I want name the post with the title in the user language if there is, else in the other language.

My `model.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title_it = Model.CharField(_('title'), max_length=64, blank=True)
    title_en = Model.CharField(_('title'), max_length=64, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        name_traslated={'title_it': self.title_it, 'title_en': self.title_en}
        name_verbose=_('title_it')
        name=name_traslated[name_verbose]
        if name=='':
            name=name_traslated['title_it']
            if name=='':
                name=name_traslated['title_en']
                if name=='':
                    name=ugettext('No Title')
```

There is some faster way to do so? For example what about this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        name_traslated={'title_it': self.title_it, 'title_en': self.title_en}
        name_verbose=_('title_it')
        name=self.title_it
        if name_traslated[name_verbose]: #!=''
            name=name_traslated[name_verbose]
        elif name==''
            name=ugettext('No Title')
        return name
```

Comment: Is Italian always preferred, followed by English?

Comment: No, but name_traslated[name_verbose] gives the title_en if the user is using the english language

Comment: Will you ever need to extend this to more languages?  For instance, prefer English, then Italian, then Schwietzer-Deutsch, then Romanche, ...

Comment: Not in my plan...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python version of a ternary operation to shorten the clauses.

```
class Post:
    title_it = 'ciao mondo'
    title_en = 'hello world'

    def __str__(self):
        name_translated = {'title_it': self.title_it, 'title_en': self.title_en}
        name_verbose = 'title_it'
        out = name_translated[name_verbose] if name_translated[name_verbose] else name_translated['title_en']
        return out if out else 'No Title'
```

Comment: But this gives always the italian title if there is, even for an english user

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your frequency of use and desired extension to more languages, you might want to maintain a preference list.  In your three-way case above, I'd generalize this with:

```
pref_list = [
    name, 
    name_translated[user_language],
    name_translated[default_language]
]
```

Now, you simply pull out the first one that has text within it.  You can do this by checking string contents or length.  The entire operation can be wrapped up in a single expression, if you like.

Comment: Probabily is better but isn't longer? I will check

Comment: It may be longer.  Is that an issue for you?  Find a solution that fits your needs, is easy to read, and easy to maintain.